# Win 32 GUI c++ .bmp The image is not showing

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, bmp, win32com

I was actually following a tutorial. I really want to get an answer because I will need to add icons to the window down the line. Getting images to show in the window would be the first step.

Sorry for some reason the update I added did not go through before. My solution is geared towards Unicode.

The corrected updated file is below :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

using namespace std;

LPCWSTR szClassName = L"myWindowClass";

HWND hLogo;
HBITMAP hLogoImage;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void loadPictures();
void parentControls(HWND);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int icmdshow)
{

    HWND hWnd;

    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };

    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;


    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc))
    {
        const wchar_t Error01[] = L"Register Issue To Check On : ";   /// Notice this 
        const wchar_t Error01_Caption[] = L"Error 01";

        MessageBoxW(NULL, Error01, Error01_Caption, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

        return 0;
    }

    LPCWSTR parentWinTitle = L"My Window";

    hWnd = CreateWindowW(szClassName, parentWinTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 250, 200, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (hWnd == NULL)
    {

        const wchar_t Error02[] = L"Window Creation Issue To Check On : ";
        const wchar_t Error02_Caption[] = L"Window Creation Issue To Check On : ";
        MessageBoxW(NULL, Error02, Error02_Caption, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

    }
    ShowWindow(hWnd, icmdshow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);


    MSG msg = { 0 };

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);

    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        loadPictures();    /// Must be called first, Calling the Images function in Create
        parentControls(hWnd);
        break;      
/*  case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wParam)
        {

        }
        break;
*/
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}


void parentControls(HWND hWnd)
{
    hLogo = CreateWindowW(WC_STATICW, NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_BITMAP, 70, 25, 100, 100, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    SendMessageW(hLogo, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hLogoImage);
}

void loadPictures()
{   /// bmp image save in file with main.cpp
    LPCWSTR myBmp = L"bitmap1.bmp";
    hLogoImage = (HBITMAP)LoadImageW(NULL, myBmp, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
}
```

Comment: You don't check return values for errors and you don't appear to have done any debugging. Why not?

Comment: Are you referring to the if statement for my register. 

    if(!RegisterClassW(&wc))
    {
        const char Error01[] = "Register Issue To Check On : ";  
        const char Error01_Caption[] = "Error 01";

        MessageBoxEx(0, Error01, Error01_Caption, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR, 0);   

        return -1;     /// Is this line incorrect???
    }


I did try debugging but having no experience with bmp in the window I lost my way.
Any direction is useful...

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `parentControls(hWnd);`

Comment: break point added. In the build log it says "Linking stage skipped (build target has no object files to link)"   .

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to post here and say, in essence, "I haven't learnt even the most basic debugging, will you debug my program". That won't help you because you still won't know how to debug. Learn to debug.

Comment: Of course that is not what I am saying.  I understand what "Linking stage skipped(build target has no object files to link)" mean.  I normally work through the errors until it is returning 0 and the code works. Any help is useful as said.

Comment: You haven't done any debugging

Comment: Just haven't had the best of luck with debuggers. I am looking into it now since you are stressing it so much. I am teaching myself. I am not looking for an answer just a direction in where I am going wrong. I went through the turtorial many times.

Comment: I have taken another look at debugging and now must humbly admit I had the wrong viewpoint on it.  I am glad now so much emphasis has been put on it. I even got visual studio c++ working better than it had been with all the freezing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(wp)
    {
    }
break;
parentControls(hWnd); <--- never gets here
loadPictures();    /// Calling the Images function in Create
break;
```

`parentControls` and `loadPictures` are never reached in this switch statement.

`loadPictures` should be called first.

Remove the two lines, put them in `WM_CREATE` as follows:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    loadPictures();    /// Calling the Images function in Create
    parentControls(hWnd);
    break;
```

Comment: Thank you, 
I should stresss that the order you add the functions in WM_CREATE can make all the difference. I had the the ParentControls(hWnd); 
listed first, with loadPictures() underneath it. When it should be the other way around.  
However the color of the bitmap is off. Any ideas why if I may ask?

Comment: Show what the picture looks like. You might have to save the image in 24-bit format. Also I recommend using Visual Studio which has a much better debugger along with other toys.

Comment: The Visual Studio tip is  a good one. I have been experimenting with it. Codeblocks is what I was using and it didn't seem to do anything when you did the debugging. I have to admit, I wasn't trying. I would work with the code to clear errors. I downloaded the 2017 community version. The difference in debugging with it was apparent right away. Good looking out.

Comment: Actually the bmp was correct. ie  [Results when program ran](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mae45/bmp-problems-one/1a9d3eb252425425ec057914c9c9547a9e5ece2d/Capture.PNG)  Took a moment to figure out how to add the pic in comments.

BTW : Thank you so much for your help. Always greatful for assistance.

mae45

Answer (score 0):

Someone told me the answer should be here instead of updated above. I am sure I will be made aware that it is wrong if I add it here. I figure that is why the updates didn't take when I tried them before in the original post above. Either way the update/Answer is below.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

using namespace std;

LPCWSTR szClassName = L"myWindowClass";

HWND hLogo;
HBITMAP hLogoImage;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void loadPictures();
void parentControls(HWND);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int icmdshow)
{

    HWND hWnd;

    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };

    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;


    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc))
    {
        const wchar_t Error01[] = L"Register Issue To Check On : ";   /// Notice this 
        const wchar_t Error01_Caption[] = L"Error 01";

        MessageBoxW(NULL, Error01, Error01_Caption, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

        return 0;
    }

    LPCWSTR parentWinTitle = L"My Window";

    hWnd = CreateWindowW(szClassName, parentWinTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 250, 200, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (hWnd == NULL)
    {

        const wchar_t Error02[] = L"Window Creation Issue To Check On : ";
        const wchar_t Error02_Caption[] = L"Window Creation Issue To Check On : ";
        MessageBoxW(0, Error02, Error02_Caption, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

    }
    ShowWindow(hWnd, icmdshow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);


    MSG msg = { 0 };

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);

    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        loadPictures();    /// Must be called first, Calling the Images function in Create
        parentControls(hWnd);
        break;      
/*  case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wParam)
        {

        }
        break;
*/
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}


void parentControls(HWND hWnd)
{
    hLogo = CreateWindowW(WC_STATICW, NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_BITMAP, 70, 25, 100, 100, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    SendMessageW(hLogo, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hLogoImage);
}

void loadPictures()
{   /// bmp image save in file with main.cpp
    LPCWSTR myBmp = L"bitmap1.bmp";
    hLogoImage = (HBITMAP)LoadImageW(NULL, myBmp, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
}
```